# Visual Studio and SQL Server Licensing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Hey I just recently started working for a company where I am the only developer for my team.  I am developing software for use only by my team.  I am unsure of what kind of license I would need for Visual Studio and SQL Server to begin development.  Does anyone have any insight on this?

Thanks Ahead

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost certainly use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) and [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products) for free.

Comment: So I can legally use it to develop an application that I will deploy to my internal server for internal use by my coworkers for free?

Comment: Yes. There's a database size limit of 10GB (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx ) but that's probably not going to worry you any time soon.